# Magento getmodel doesn't work, I need to retrieve customer ID by email

Tags: magento

I need to retrieve the customer ID by email, I have tried like this:

```
    $collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('email', 'costumeremail@gmail.com')
   ->addAttributeToSort('customer_id', 'ASC');
echo (string)$collection->getSelect();
```

but it always return error 500;
What's wrong?

Is there any way to retrieve customer info by email?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use standard features magento:

```
$customerEmail = 'someemail@sample.com';
```

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
$customerId = $customer->getId();

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: i put it on getCustomer.php in the root folder.. am i wrong? where to put the php view file?

Comment: To find the cause of the error 500, you need to see the server error_log

Comment: o jeee makajeeeeee  ; i should put  umask(0);
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); in the head or the file

Comment: and customer_id should be entity_id